# console.log not parsing css styling

Tags: javascript, css, console.log

I wanted to make text in console.log display in an array of rainbow colours. The problem is that the console doesn't seem to parse the styling. Instead when I try `rainbowify(myString);` in the console, it is outputting the literal string. I've already tried `toString()` which didn't work.

The odd part is that if I copy and paste the output and put it into console log (in the console) it works fine. I need to understand why it isn't parsing the css styling, but is just outputting it as a string.

```js
var myString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var rainbow = ["red", "yellow", "pink", "green", "purple", "orange", "blue"];

function rainbowify(string) {
  var splitString = string.split("");
  var stringConCat = "";
  var stringCss = "";
  for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < splitString.length; i++, j++) {
    stringConCat += "\"%c" + splitString[i] + "\"" + " + ";
    stringCss += "\"color : " + rainbow[j] + "\"" + ", ";
    if (j === rainbow.length - 1) {
      j = 0;
    }
  }
  var stringSliced = stringConCat.slice(0, -3);
  var cssSliced = stringCss.slice(0, -2);
  console.log(stringSliced + ", " + cssSliced);
}
```

Comment: Your code produces a string that contains JavaScript, and your `console.log` just outputs that string. When you copy and paste the string, into your console, you're evaluating it. Consider the difference between `console.log("%ca", "color: red")` and `console.log('"%ca", "color: red"')` or simply `x = 1 + 2` vs `x = "1 + 2"`.

Comment: As mentioned in the description, I am calling the function from the console.

Comment: @meagar I thought that might be the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're producing a string that contains a bunch of JavaScript. When you copy and paste that string into your console (without quotes), then the JavaScript is evaluated. When you pass that string directly to `console.log`, the string itself is output.

You are producing strings like this:

```
"\"%ca\" + \"%cb\", \"color : red\", \"color : green\""
```

When you `console.log` the result, you're invoking `log` with a single string argument, which logs the string as given:

```
 console.log("\"%ca\" + \"%cb\", \"color : red\", \"color : green\"");
```

The *correct* invocation would be *three* arguments:

```
 console.log("%ca%cb", "color : red", "color : green")
```

Instead of outputting this string containing a bunch of `+` concatenations and comma-separated arguments, you should be producing an array of arguments and invoking `console.log` with `apply`:

```
["%ca%cb", "color : red", "color : green"]
```

```js
var rainbow = ["red", "yellow", "pink", "green", "purple", "orange", "blue"];

function rainbowify(string) {
  var splitString = string.split("");
  var formatString = "";
  var colorArguments = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < splitString.length; ++i) {
    formatString += "%c" + splitString[i];
    colorArguments.push("color : " + rainbow[i % rainbow.length]);
  }

  return [formatString].concat(colorArguments);
}


// output the array
console.log(rainbowify("test string"));

// Invoke console.log with the array as its arguments
console.log.apply(console, rainbowify("test string"));
```

Note that StackOverflow's faux console doesn't support color. The actual output of the above snippet renders like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simplified implementation of your function using `.reduce()` and `.map()`.

```js
var myString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var rainbow = ["red", "yellow", "pink", "green", "purple", "orange", "blue"];

function rainbowify(string) {
  var strArr = string.split("");
  var logs = [strArr.reduce((result, char) => result.concat("%c" + char + " "), "")];
    
  var logsWithColors = logs.concat(strArr.map((char, i) => {
    return "color: " + rainbow[i % rainbow.length] + ";"
  }));

  console.log.apply(console, logsWithColors);
}

rainbowify(myString);
```

Produces the following in the browser's console:

[image]